# Changing CSS on Blackberry

Tags: javascript, css, dom, blackberry

I have the following piece of code, inspired by twitter bootstrap. It works perfectly on everything except the Blackberry Curve 8200.

It's basically to open and close navigation.

The events are triggering, the state is being picked up correctly but when I adjust css nothing happens :( I've tried adding and removing classes instead, same problem.

The collapsed element does display correctly if i add a style attribute to it manually as well.

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').bind('click', collapse);

function collapse (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var target = $this.data('target');
    var state = $this.data('state');
    if ( ! state ) state = 'closed'; 

    if ( state === 'closed' ) {
        $(target).css('height', 'auto');
        $this.data('state', 'open');
    } else {
        $(target).css('height', '0');
        $this.data('state', 'closed');
    }
    return false;
}
```

It basically seems like the following line

```
$(target).css('height', 'auto');
```

just isn't doing anything. Even though the target variable is correct.

My html essentially looks like this

```
<style>
    .nav { height: 0; }
</style>
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav">...</div>
<div class="nav">...</div>
```

-update-

I was using zepto, just tried with jQuery... same problem.

Comment: is it me or target is just some user data? (which does not have a css) you should change the selector to the element (this).

Comment: target is the selector for the content that the button targets.

Comment: can you show markup please? i think you are selecting the element in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Is this OS5 or OS6? If OS5, there are all sorts of defects with the browser supporting DOM re-rendering. `height: auto` being one of them. The solution I've used is to show them on page load, measure then cache their original height via a `data-*` attribute, then collapse them all. That way when it's time to show them, instead of `auto` I can give an exact pixel dimension.

Comment: OS5, is there documentation on the rendering bugs? I'm going to try a regular toggle() instead

Comment: Documentation? Ahahahaha! Sorry. That was an insane stress related laugh. Alas, no, the defects in OS5 are plentiful, and sporadically documented. Usually it's a matter of bugging the RIM forums waiting for a RIM dev to eventually confirm that it's a defect. Toggle might work, though note that toggling `display` between `block` and `hidden` can also cause issues in certain scenarios. We eventually dropped OS5 support due to the amount of browser defects.

Comment: okay, thanks.
Just tried storing heights as data attributes, but when I try and set all the heights to 0 after that it doesn't work... :(